# Allow content to overlap multi-column layout

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns, css-multicolumn-layout

I'm trying to allow content to overlap multiple columns, ignoring the boundaries set by the multi-column layout properties.

The problem is that regardless of `position`, `overflow` or `z-index`, the columns will never allow content from a previous column to overlap and will cut off the content - as if overflow is set to `hidden`.

Is it possible to override this behaviour? Hover on the elements in the snippet to see an example of this behaviour.

```css
body {
  background-color: silver;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 1em;
  -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
  -moz-column-gap: 1em;
}

.container div {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2em 0;
  background: #2980b9;
  color: white;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.container div:hover:after {
  content: 'I\'m overlapping!';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think there is a way to override the behavior, and even if there were, this does not seem to be the right approach. Can you explain what you are trying to achieve in the end ? Maybe there is a completely different and better way of achieving your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `:after` you can just use `position:fixed`, the `:after` will simply position it in the correct location, to my understanding! so that the image is positioned relative to the viewport, also you need to make adjustments like `width:auto` because `width:100%` will take the width of the screen and `z-index:3000` is also needed to show the text above the divs.

```css
body {
  background-color: silver;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 1em;
  -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
  -moz-column-gap: 1em;
}

.container div {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2em 0;
  background: #2980b9;
  color: white;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.container div:hover:after {
  content: 'I\'m overlapping, like a lot!!';
  position: fixed;
  width: auto;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  z-index:3000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```